# How to add JEL classification codes in elsarticle submission

Tags: elsarticle

A few days ago I used the proposed elsarticle latex class template in order to prepare and submit an original article to a finance related journal of Elsevier. The editor sent me back the submission, asking me to 1-6 JEL classification code(s). Thus, I provided six JEL classification codes in the Editorial Manager (i.e. the submission platform) and made a new submission thereafter.  However, the editor sent me back the manuscript again, asking for JEL classification codes to appear right after the keywords section.  Having provided the JEL classification codes in the submission platform, I am not sure what to do next.

Now I am thinking that maybe I should add the JEL codes inside the .tex files. However, elsarticle has no instructions for adding JEL codes.

**Question:
How can I add JEL Classification codes under the paper's keywords section given that I am using the elsarticle template?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, I 've highlighted the main question in concise format:
How can I add JEL Classification codes under the paper's keywords section given that I am using the elsarticle template?

Comment: Does`elsarticle` have a `\keywords` command?  The logical approach would be to clone that, but that is best done by the creator/maintainer of the document class.  (I know that isn't a satisfying answer, but if it is a required component, it should be provided by the source.)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `elsarticle` should tell you how to do it, but it doesn't. Anyway, it's not difficult.

```
\begin{frontmatter}

% title and author information here

\begin{abstract}
This is the text of the abstract.
This is the text of the abstract.
This is the text of the abstract.
This is the text of the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
test \sep key \sep word

\JEL A10 \sep B21 \sep C42
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
```

[image]